# UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, autocorrect, uikeyboardtype

I have two buttons leftBtn and rightBtn respectively, and one UITextField.

When user taps on leftBtn, I have code below,

```
 [textField resignFirstResponder];
 textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```

when user taps on rightBtn, I have following code,

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes;
```

So when right button is tapped I see autocorrect and when left button is tapped I don't see autocorrect.

It works fine but when from right button I pick text from autocorrect and then if I switch to left button it shows keyboard with autocorrect until I have autocorrect text entered in my textfield.

It bypass the line

```
textfield.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes;
```

But doesn't hide autocorrect until I remove character entered.

Comment: What you are asking exactly ? can't understand because your code seems perfect. when you click right btn it will show autocorrection and when left then it will hide. nothing wrong in it i think

Comment: No need for resignFirstResponder, Rather is should be becomeFirstResponder

Comment: this works desirable for english characters but not for chinese characters

Comment: as my autocorrect type is no and if user start type it starts giving the suggestions all over again